# Node js / socket / verify is not a function

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Hello wanted to understand what causes this error:
is not a function
(what I missed to make it happen)

I'm trying to validate my jwt by connecting my io socket with this:

```
  io.use(verify.authSocket(socket)
  .on('connection', function(socket) {
      socket.on('message', function(message) {
          io.emit('message', message);
      });
  }));
```

this is mt verify.authSocket:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/User')
const config= require('../config/dbconfig');
const moment = require('moment');

module.exports = {
    async authSocket(socket,next){
        const token = socket.handshake.query.token;
        if(!token) return next(new Error('Unauthorized'));
        try{
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token,config.secretToken);
            if(decoded){    
                next();
            }else{
                next(new Error('Authentication error')); 
            }
        }catch(error){
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
}
```

error:

```
C:\Users\SpiriT\Documents\Projetos\FtcJokenPo\back\src\app.js:25
  .on('connection', function(socket) {
   ^

TypeError: verify.authSocket(...).on is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SpiriT\Documents\Projetos\FtcJokenPo\back\src\app.js:25:4)
```

I am trying to understand what causes this error

I thought my verify.authsocket was a function, could someone explain me and help me fix this error?

Comment: Seems you have a missing ')' in `io.use(verify.authSocket(socket))`

Comment: Really omg, 
I have an error I don't know where I went wrong, I believe it was in my front end : 
 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/socket.io/?token=%22eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOjIsImVtYWlsIjoiaGFiYm9vZ3JvQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImFkbWluIjp0cnVlLCJpYXQiOjE1NzQyNzkyMzYsImV4cCI6MTU3NDI3OTgzNn0.E2bsrjq87VWXcfbT8dB97AqDZf4s1aYMpRd1YDypQe0%22&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=Jvwaf_byTlNReqYBAAAA' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: in my backend i receive this error: C:\Users\SpiriT\Documents\Projetos\FtcJokenPo\back\node_modules\socket.io\lib\namespace.js:124
    fns[i](socket, function(err){
          ^

TypeError: fns[i] is not a function

Comment: Can you help me ?

Comment: Check my answer, that error is explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`verify.authSocket` is indeed a function. The error is telling you that the returned value from `verify.authSocket` is not a function, hence the `(...)` in the error message

```
 io.use(verify.authSocket(socket)) // added )
  .on('connection', function(socket) {
      socket.on('message', function(message) {
          io.emit('message', message);
      });
  });
```

In your code you were attaching `.on` to the return value of `verify.authSocket` instead of adding it to `io`

Have in mind that while the errors are similar, they're not the same:

- `TypeError: verify.authSocket(...) is not a function` indicates that **the returned value** of `verify.authSocket` is not a function
- `TypeError: verify.authSocket(...).on is not a function` indicates that **the returned value** of `verify.authSocket` doesn't have an `.on` property which is a function
- `TypeError: verify.authSocket is not a function` indicates that `verify.authSocket` is not a function

---

In any case, `io.use` expects a `function` as argument, and you're not passing one. `verify.authSocket` must return a valid middleware or just be one.

So just use: `verify.authSocket` instead of `verify.authSocket(socket)`

```
io.use(verify.authSocket)
  .on('connection', function(socket) {
      socket.on('message', function(message) {
          io.emit('message', message);
      });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, got it and managed to get into my if (decoded)

 I have an error
and I can't return my message

(node: 19004) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at Object.authSocket (C: \ Users \ SpiriT \ Documents \ Projects \ FtcJokenPo \ back \ src \ auth \ index.js: 42: 40)
    at Socket. <anonymous> (C: \ Users \ SpiriT \ Documents \ Projects \

Comment: I recommend adding a new question, for that error, since it's out of the scope of the first issue. I'll have to see what's on line 42, too.

Comment: I managed to solve this problem was a second function that called my "connection", but I still have a problem with my middlware it authenticates but when it reaches my socket.on ('message' it does not enter

Comment: if you can help me : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58966068/nodejs-socket-io-jwt-middlware

Comment: And somehow when I get into my middlware I'm already logged in (I did some testing on this, not after I validate my jwt)